# How to update vForm input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I'm using [vForm](https://github.com/cretueusebiu/vform) with [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/), And I'm using a bootstrap modal to edit an event on the calendar. when I'm clicking an event on the calendar it's opening the modal with the form and it's input's and I'm sending the data's to the vForm from Fullcalendar eventclick() method but it's not showing in the form and the form inputs are empty. here's what I tried so far which none of them works and I added comments to make things more clear:

**FAILURE 1:**

```
<script>
import "fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.js";
import "fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.css";
import { Form, HasError, AlertError } from "vform";

Vue.component(HasError.name, HasError);
Vue.component(AlertError.name, AlertError);

var editTitle = "";
var editStart = "";
var editEnd = "";
var editdesc = "";

export default {
  props: ["workingHours"],
  mounted() {
    const date = new Date();
    const d = date.getDate();
    const m = date.getMonth();
    const y = date.getFullYear();

    const events = this.workingHours;

    $("#full-calendar").fullCalendar({
      events,
      height: 800,
      header: {
        left: "month,agendaWeek,agendaDay",
        center: "title",
        right: "today prev,next"
      },
      eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
        editStart = calEvent.start.format("MM/DD/YYYY, h:mm a");
        editEnd = calEvent.end.format("MM/DD/YYYY, h:mm a");
        editTitle = calEvent.title;
        editdesc = calEvent.desc;
        var xpos = jsEvent.pageX;
        var ypos = jsEvent.pageY;
        $("#calendar-edit").modal("show");
        console.log(editTitle); //at this stage the editTitle variable is updated with the new value but down in the form the title is not updated with the new value

        return false;
      }
    });
  },
  data() {
    return {
      // Create a new form instance
      form: new Form({
        title: editTitle, //here the value is not updated with the new value so the input in the form is empty
        start: editStart,
        end: editEnd,
        desc: editdesc
      })
    };
  },

  methods: {
    updateEvent() {
      // Submit the form via a PUT request
      this.form.put("/api/workinghours/update/" + 1).then(({ data }) => { //don't worry about the plus one i'm using it for testing purpose
        console.log(data);
      });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

**FAILURE 2:**

```
<script>
import "fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.js";
import "fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.css";
import { Form, HasError, AlertError } from "vform";

Vue.component(HasError.name, HasError);
Vue.component(AlertError.name, AlertError);

export default {
  props: ["workingHours"],
  mounted() {
    const date = new Date();
    const d = date.getDate();
    const m = date.getMonth();
    const y = date.getFullYear();

    const events = this.workingHours;

    $("#full-calendar").fullCalendar({
      events,
      height: 800,
      header: {
        left: "month,agendaWeek,agendaDay",
        center: "title",
        right: "today prev,next"
      },
      eventClick: function(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
        this.form.start = calEvent.start.format("MM/DD/YYYY, h:mm a");
        this.form.end = calEvent.end.format("MM/DD/YYYY, h:mm a");
        this.form.title = calEvent.title; //So for this I'm using the Vform's API to update the values but it gives error that the title is not defined
        this.form.desc = calEvent.desc;
        var xpos = jsEvent.pageX;
        var ypos = jsEvent.pageY;
        $("#calendar-edit").modal("show");
        return false;
      }
    });
  },
  data() {
    return {
      // Create a new form instance
      form: new Form({
        title: "", //here the value  still is not updated with the new value so the input in the form is empty
        start: "",
        end: "",
        desc: ""
      })
    };
  },

  methods: {
    updateEvent() {
      // Submit the form via a PUT request
      this.form.put("/api/workinghours/update/" + 1).then(({ data }) => { //don't worry about the plus one i'm using it for testing purpose
        console.log(data);
      });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: Any specific reason why you used an old version of fullCalendar, and didn't use fullCalendar's ready-made Vue component? See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vue . I'm not a vue expert but I can't help thinking it might make your integration easier.

Comment: I'm using Adminator https://github.com/puikinsh/Adminator-admin-dashboard and Fullcalendar is already included and I'm not sure if it's an old version of Fullcalendar or no because that's the first time I'm using it.

Comment: yes it's an old version, it's version 3. version 4 is current, and 5 will be available soon. No more updates or fixes for 3 will be released as far as I know. So it's not a good time to start using it. Since it's just defined as script in your page, I think you can easily replace it with the newer version.

Comment: Thank you for your help I will update it then, But still if you check the code, The issue is not with the fullcalendar it's with vForm.

Comment: yes but if you recall, my thought was that using a vue component to represent the calendar might help with integration. I don't know vue but it seems like you have an issue either with variable scope, or with timing about how/when values are collected into the form object.

Comment: I have updated to the latest 4.4 version and transfered to fullcalendar.io/docs/vue you mentioned. now I don't have access to the event object https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object I only have @dateClick which it's not the one I want because it's only an event that triggered when clicking the days not the events.

Comment: You do have access to all of it. There are no missing features. the dateClick is given just as an example. But you can use eventClick just the same way. (Note eventClick not eventObject!).

Comment: @ADyson can you please show me and example please I did it that way but I don't have access to the data: <FullCalendar
      defaultView="dayGridMonth"
      :events="workingHours"
      @eventClick="handleDateClick"
    /> and the the method: handleDateClick(calEvent, jsEvent, view) {
        this.form.title = calEvent;
      $("#calendar-edit").modal("show");
    },

Comment: Did you check the [v4 documentation for eventClick](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventClick)? or the [v3-v4 upgrade guide](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v3)? The function signature has changed. There's now just one incoming object into the function, which contains all the different items as properties within it. (And even if it hadn't changed, it would make no sense to assign the entire event object to your title field, the way your code is trying to do.).

Comment: `handleDateClick(info) { this.form.title = info.event.title; $("#calendar-edit").modal("show"); }` would would make more sense I think.

Comment: P.S. if you're using vue, why are you then also using jquery/bootstrap code to display things? I'm pretty sure vue has a way it expects you to do that kind of thing. If you're going to use a UI framework like vue, it would make sense to use it consistently throughout your application, otherwise you'll probably just confuse yourself (and anyone else who has to work with your code), and/or introduce bugs, or hard-to-solve problems later on when not everything is done to the same standard.

Comment: I did the exact same thing but still not receiving the data and I did both the way @eventClick="handleDateClick" and @eventClick="handleDateClick(info)"

Comment: I'm a Laravel framework developer I don't have much experience with frontend frameworks and javascript. but as far as I know that's how most of the things work when combining Laravel with vue. anyway now the eventClick is working but not sending the info. thanks for your time

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and your time. It's working now. Thank you again

Comment: what did you change to get it working? You should write it as an Answer below, in case anyone else is struggling in a similar way.

Comment: I had a typo error, I used: handleDateClick(info) { this.form.title = info.event.title; $("#calendar-edit").modal("show"); } I will add the answer later for sure. Thank you

Comment: No I mean write it properly in the "Your Answer" section below. It's allowed to answer your own question. And then others can upvote it if it helps them or they like it. P.S. that's no different to what I told you to write already?

Comment: I know I will add it later, I'm working on my project now. I want to write the answer properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So with the help of @ADyson I could make it work thanks to him, I have been using an old version first and updated to the latest version and changed the Fullcalendar library to VUE version. so now the event click is triggered is changing the input values of the vForm I will add the entire code below trying to add comments too. the only issue now is beside using vForm and Fullcalendar libraries I'm using [vue-datetime](https://github.com/mariomka/vue-datetime) and when sending the values to the form the  component input value is empty I think the issue is more related to the datetime format in javascript, So I have tricked to add badge over the datetime components to show the old values. I know it's not the right way of doing it but for now it's good

```
<script>
import FullCalendar from "@fullcalendar/vue";
import dayGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/daygrid";
import timeGridPlugin from "@fullcalendar/timegrid";
import interactionPlugin from "@fullcalendar/interaction";

var eventID = 0;
export default {
  props: ["workingHours"],
  components: {
    FullCalendar // make the <FullCalendar> tag available
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      calendarPlugins: [
        // plugins must be defined in the JS
        dayGridPlugin,
        timeGridPlugin,
        interactionPlugin // needed for dateClick
      ],
      calendarWeekends: true,
      form: new Form({
        title: "",
        start: "",
        end: "",
        desc: ""
      })
    };
  },
  methods: {
    handleDateClick(info) {
        eventID = info.event.id;
        const startTime = moment(info.event.start).format('yyyy-MM-DD hh:MM:SS');
        const endTime = moment(info.event.end).format('yyyy-MM-DD hh:MM:SS');
        this.form.title = info.event.title;
        this.form.start = startTime;
        this.form.end = endTime;
        this.form.desc = info.event.extendedProps.desc;
        $("#disabledStart").html(startTime);
        $("#disabledEnd").html(endTime);
        $("#calendar-edit").modal("show");
        console.log(info.event.start);
        console.log(startTime);
        console.log(info.event.id);
    },
    updateEvent() {
      // Submit the form via a PUT request
      this.form.put("/api/workinghours/update/" + eventID).then(({ data }) => {
        console.log(data);
        $("#calendar-edit").modal("hide");
      });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```